# use other command instead of ssh for ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have an ansible configuration which I know works on my local machines. However, I'm trying to now set it up on my company's machines which use a wrapper command similar to ssh (let's call it 'myssh')

for example, to access these machines, instead of writing

```
ssh myuser@123.123.123.123
```

you write

```
myssh myuser@123.123.123.123
```

which ends up calling ssh, among other things.

My question is, is there a way to swap which command ansible uses for accessing machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [Connection Type Plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#connection-type-plugins) to archive this. Looking at the ssh plugin, it appears like it might be as easy as replacing the `ssh_cmd` in [line 333](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/connections/ssh.py#L333). Also specify `myssh` in [line 69](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/connections/ssh.py#L69).

See [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#distributing-plugins) where to place the modified file. Additionally to that information, you can specify a custom location and let Ansible know about it in [`connection_plugins` setting in `ansible.cfg`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#connection-plugins).

Finally again in your `ansible.cfg` set the [`transport` setting](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#transport) to your new plugin:

```
transport = myssh
```

*PS: I have never done anything like that before. This is only info from the docs.*

Comment: cool. totally missed that in the docs. but when i tried this i got: "FAILED => unsupported connection type: myssh". Is it possible the "transport" command only supports known transport commands? I'll keep looking into it

Comment: As written I haven't done this myself yet. But from what I understand the transport "name" will be what is returned in the `transport` method of the plugin, which is in line 69 of the ssh plugin. If the module then is placed into the correct folder or configured to be found through ansible.cfg, I _think_ it should be working.

Comment: actually, i ended up getting it working. Everything you said was correct except I had a problem with making my custom plugin in /etc/ansible/plugins. It said I was missing some Ansible packages in python. I ended up finding the real plugin directory in /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/1.9.1_1/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/runner/connection_plugins. I had to change a few things to make it work with the myssh program, but then it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your `myssh` command is a drop-in replacement for `ssh`, then you can tell Ansible to use it directly without creating a connection plugin using the [ssh_executable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#parameter-ssh_executable) configuration:

You can either put the following in your config file:

```ini
[ssh_connection]
ssh_executable = myssh
```

Or you can set an environment variable:

```bash
ANSIBLE_SSH_EXECUTABLE=myssh ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml
```

Or you can set a variable (in your playbook for example):

```yaml
- name: Example
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_executable: myssh
```

If you are using a wrapper and you don't have a wrapper version of `scp` or `sftp`, then you can direct Ansible to pipe data through SSH instead by configuring [ssh_transfer_method](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#parameter-ssh_transfer_method) to `piped`. Use the same method as above to configure.